# RemoveAt does not remove from the specified index

Tags: c#

My exercise is to sum equal numbers in a `List<T>`. When I call `RemoveAt(int index)`, it doesn't remove at the specified index, it removes the last index of the list.

```
private static int GetNumberFromInput(List<int> input)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == input.Count - 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (input[i] == input[i + 1])
        {
            sum = input[i] + input[i + 1];
            input.RemoveAt(i);
            input[i] = sum;
            i--;
        }

        if (input[i] != input[i + 1])
        {
            if(input[i+1] == input[i + 2])
            {
                sum = input[i + 1] + input[i + 2];
                input.RemoveAt(input[i + 1]);
                input[i + 1] = sum;
            }
            i--;
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What is this loop meant to do?

Comment: `input.RemoveAt(input[i + 1]);` doesn't look right to me

Comment: you could use Linq expression to do the sum - unless the assignment says you can't

Comment: Var result = input.groupby(x=> x).select(x=> x.sum()).tolist();

Comment: @eocron You are missing a `.Where` there

Comment: Umm why i need to use where? Im just summing all equal numbers. Single numbers will stay at place. OP did no state any filtering conditions.

Comment: @eocron [Are you sure that single numbers won't count?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NtquPC)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `input.RemoveAt(input[i + 1]);` should probably just be `input.RemoveAt(i + 1);`.

But even that will cause problems for you.

Let's say you have a list with 5 items (indexes 0 through 4) with values 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', and 'E'.

You call `myList.RemoveAt(3)`. This will remove the item at index 3, which is `D`. The list now has elements 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'E'. However, it does **NOT** have indexes 0, 1, 2, and 4. It has indexes 0, 1, 2, and 3. The last item (`E`) is now at index 3 instead of index 4.

If you need to also remove the index value 3, so that 0, 1, 2, and 4 remain, what you really want is a [*Dictionary*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) with an integer key.

This code is especially scary because it happens in the middle of a loop. Later references in the loop body to `input[i]` are now referring to the next item. In particular, it's poor practice to modify a collection of any type while you iterate (loop) through it. If you *must* do this, the better option is to start at the back/end and work towards the front/beginning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the loop never ends if all the elements are different.

Anyhow, So say we have a `List<int> list` with 3 items in it.

```
int i = 0; // will be owr index
list[0] = 4;
list[1] = 4;
list[2] = 3;
```

Now when you say `input.RemoveAt(i);` `i = 0`.

The list becomes like this :

```
list[0] = 4;
list[1] = 3;
```

Then you go and say `input[i] = sum;` `i=0 , sum=8`

The list becomes like this :

```
list[0] = 8;
list[1] = 3;
```

One workaround would be to

```
input[i] = sum; // repalce the item 
input.RemoveAt(i+1); // then remove the  next one, since they're identical.
```

I'm sure there is a lot of ways around this, but the main issue here was that you didn't understand what was happening.